# Query Many to many gives me ZERO results

Tags: mysql

im working on this tables

tbl company

```
|idcompany |   name   |
|   1      |   apple  |
|   2      |    ms    |
|   3      |   pepsi  |
```

tbl vendor

```
| idbrand  |   vName   |
|    1     | comp soft |
|    2     |   food    |
|    3     |Electronics|
```

tbl vendorXcompany

```
| idbrand  | idcompany |
|    1     |      1    |
|    2     |      3    |
|    1     |      2    |
|    3     |      2    |
```

I need to know what companies belong to electronics and computer software

in this case that would be

1 - ms

this query does not return any results

```
SELECT * FROM company c
JOIN vendorXcompany vc ON c.idcompany = vc.idcompany
JOIN vendor v ON vc.idbrand = v.idbrand
WHERE vc.idbrand = 1 and vc.idbrand = 3
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHERE` condition excludes all rows because `vc.idbrand = 1` and `vc.idbrand = 3` cannot both be true at once. What you need to do is find companies which have matches against both by counting rows which match *either* condition:

```
SELECT c.idcompany, c.name
FROM company c
JOIN vendorXcompany vc ON c.idcompany = vc.idcompany
JOIN vendor v ON vc.idbrand = v.idbrand
WHERE vc.idbrand = 1 OR vc.idbrand = 3
GROUP BY c.idcompany
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Output:

```
idcompany   name
2           ms
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c0103/1)

Comment: Great. Thank you so much!